# React-native Redux. Store data not available to component on first mount

Tags: react-native, redux, store

caveat: I have scoured the docs.

I am looking for the best way to hydrate (populate) component fields with data from a slice of state when component mounts (or perhaps right after the component mounts in componentDidMount).

I am trying to write a summary page of data from a form that I previously filled out. When I "submit" the form I navigate to the summary page for user verification. What I would like is the summary page to be 'connected' to the store so that when it mounts first time the store data is available to the component through the props (as usual) and populates the fields. However, I suspect the "Summary" component only rerenders with the new data when the slice of state, that it (the summary page) is connected to, gets updated.

What is the best way to mount a page that populates the fields with data from the store when it mounts.

My options are:
1)(worst ones first) On componentDidMount fake an update to that slice of state, causing a rerender, which in turn will cause a rerender to the summary page with the slice's data.
2)Simply getState from the store on componentDidMount
3)Use selectors and return a Promise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there summary page a different route (page)? If you want to render another component with part of the state, just access that part of the state (I might not have enough info to answer this question). Sounds like a good excuse to use Redux though

Comment: Yes, I could access the state from the component. But I believe the state should be accessed with a promise (should be async - is this true?). THe issue is that I do not pass the store down to the components. It felt bloated to do so. In other words I can't access store.getState(). It seems better to use selectors in redux-sagas to return a promise that yields the slice of state I requested. Currently I access the store by dispathcing an action and updating the slice of state I want which triggers a rerender on the component and displays the values. This also seems wrong.